# OpenCV: GoPro video editing blur

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gopro

I am attempting to post-process a video in OpenCV. The problem is that the GoPro video is very blurry, even with a high frame rate.

Is there any way that I can remove blur? I've heard about deinterlacing, but don't know if this applies to a GoPro 3+, or where even to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need more light in your acquisition environment. Can you achieve that? Otherwise removing blur it's a fairly difficult problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104322/2436175

Comment: I actually don't think my lighting is terrible. It will be tough to add more, but it is possible. However, I'm surprised by how much blur I am seeing even at 60 fps on a go pro (action can).

Comment: Do you get blurry video even in bright sunlight without moving the subject and/or camera? Then I’d rather think that your hardware is not ok (e.g., scratches or moisture on lense).

Answer (score 0):

You can record at a high frame rate to remove any blur, also make sure you are recording with enough natural light, so recording outdoors is recommended.

Look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nU2_ERC_oE

At 30 fps, there is some blur in the car, but at 60fps the blur is non existant, just doubling the FPS can do some good. Since you have a HERO3+ you can record 720p 60 and that will remove the blur. WVGA 120fps can also do some [justice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9Xsk7noL-U) (example is 1080p but still applies)